# How to generate an apk in Eclipse with files used in the emulator?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk

I'm having trouble with an app. I've developed it in Eclipse and I'm creating and modifying text files that are stored in the data/data/project name/files/ of the emulated device.

When I generate the apk of it, those files will not be stored anywhere, so I can not access them and the application stops working.

Does anyone have idea how I can generate the apk and that these files are also saved within the application?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. You need to either generate your files other way and include in your apk during build process (usually stored in `assets/` folder of your project) or get it from emulator and rebuild your apk including these files in your apk during build process (usually stored in `assets/` folder of your project)

Comment: But in the assets/ folder i can modify them, right?

Comment: The same way you modify your sources - prior final export. But not at runtime. APK is read-only once is built.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.If I can't modify the files if they are in the assets folder, what can I do?

Comment: Why would you want to modify a file in assets folder? The usual way is to copy them at runtime from assets to internal memory. There you can modify them.

Comment: I do not want modify a file in assets folder, I want modify just like I did in Eclipse. To copy to internal memory the file, what I have to do?

Comment: `I want modify just like I did in Eclipse.`. ? Well i don't know what you did to do that. But now your app has to do the modification.